# how to install oracle 10g xe on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: software-installation, oracle

I have read from [here](http://starodubtsevss.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/oracle10g-xe-on-ubuntu-64bit/) how to install oracle 10g xe in ubuntu 10.x but not in 11.04 (64 bit). But with 11.04 it does not work anymore because of dependency exceptions. So, how to install oracle 10g xe in ubuntu 11.04?

I even found some variant how to fix it [from here](http://littlebrain.org/2008/05/12/how-to-install-oracle-xe-in-ubuntu-64-bit/#comment-194921589) but in my case it does not work - the same exception take place:

> oracle-xe-universal:i386 depends on
>   libc6 (>= 2.3.2); however: Package
>   libc6:i386 is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemes to me that package is broken. If I understand it correctly, libc latest version is 2.14 (http://www.eglibc.org/home)

So you should rebuild this package without this dependency to install it.

Comment: Hmmm.. It installs smoothly on my Ubuntu 9.10. But libc6 version there is 2.10.1-0ubuntu19. I don't understand. =(

Comment: Oh, looks like it's a glitch with version comparison. Version: 2.13-0ubuntu13 should fit this requirement: libc6 (>= 2.3.2)

Comment: yes i delete all deps from there... and repacked it. now it works.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the deb file, open Oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386/DEBIAN/control and remove the dependency for libc6 so you end up with:

Depends: libaio (>= 0.3.96) | libaio1 (>= 0.3.96)

Then cd to the directory that contains the extracted folders and do a dpkg-deb --build oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386 && sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same content that I have seen in the link that I've mentioned above. It does not help me. See above.

Comment: It helped me, thanks. May be I only needed --force-architecture but it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to install the 32 bits libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install libaio
```

Start installation of oracle express:

```
dpkg -i --force-architecture oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb
```

Configure it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

Add required environment variable to `.bashrc`:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines to it:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_HOME
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export PATH
```